# SQL Server select query is slow. Can we Improve performance without creating indexes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

What to do to get data in 0 sec on a table that keeps increasing every day.
I know creating indexes would improve the select speed I don't want to create index which will in future slow down the insert/update speed.

Is there anything else we can do to improve the select performance.

For example: Simple query like

```
Select Count(id) from data
```

takes 4 sec

[image]

**Update: As requested here is the Execution Plan**

[image]

Comment: Well if you don't want to add an index, then I would suggest a bigger machine with a RAM drive

Comment: You need to review the Execution Plan used by Sql Server during execution. That will tell you if you can optimize the query or do index tuning. Without sharing that there is not much else the community can do for you.

Comment: Added execution plan.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you ID column have an index.

for "Select Count(id) from data" on 4 sec by 1722000 records is good speed, is not a problem.

You have a problem when queries with any clause are slow, then you need to use index to "some" fields